# Handling invalid states in haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to get a better feel for how to handle error states in Haskell, since there seem to be a lot of ways to do it.  Ideally, my data structures would make any invalid inputs unrepresentable, but despite considerable effort to the contrary, I still occasionally end up working with data where the type system can allow invalid states.  As an example, let's consider that my program input is the training results for a neural network.  In order for math to work, each matrix needs to have the correct bounds, and that's not (really) representable by the type system.  If data is invalid, there's really nothing the application can do but halt any further processing and notify someone of the problem (so it's not recoverable).  What's the best way to handle this in Haskell?  It seems like I could:

1) Use `error` or other partial functions when processing my data.  My understanding is this should only be used to represent a bug in the code.  So it would have to be coupled with some sort of validation at the point that I load the data, and any point "after" that check I just assume that the data is in a valid format.  This feels imperative to me, and doesn't seem to fit very well with lazy, declarative code.

2) Throw an exception when processing the data using `Control.Exception.throw`, and then catch it at the top level where I can alert someone.  Contrary to `error`, I believe this doesn't indicate a bug in the program, so perhaps there wouldn't be verification when I load the data beyond what can be represented through the type system?  The presence or absence of an exception when processing the data would define the verification.

3) Lift any data processing that could fail into the IO monad and use `Control.Exception.throwIO`.

4) Lift any data processing that could fail into the IO monad and use `fail` (I've read that using `fail` frowned on by the community?)

5) Return an `Either` or something similar, and let that bubble up through all your logic.  I've definitely had some cases where composing `Either`s becomes (to me) exceedingly impractical.

6) Use Control.Monad.Exception, which I only marginally understand, but seems to involve lifting any data processing that could fail into some exceptional monad, that I think is supposed to be more easily composeable than `Either`?

and I'm not even sure that's all the options.  Is there an approach to this problem that's generally accepted by the community, or is this really an opinionated topic?

Comment: Using a suitable monad is fairly common for errors/exceptions. `Either e` is fine, and even `Maybe` could be appropriate. `Except e` is essentially `Either e` with a better name. `MonadException` generalizes all these approaches, but its generality is not often needed (IMO). I'd stay away from IO, as a default, since that will make every catch to be possible only inside IO. Forget about `fail`, rather use `Control.Monad.Exception.throw` or something more specific like `throwE`.

Comment: As a very tame example, I recently had to convert a `[IO (Either Text [Either Text Int])]` to an `IO (Either Text [[Int]])` in just a toy project, which required a lot more thought than seemed reasonable to me.  Wouldn't that problem continue to escalate the deeper you are into your program logic?

Comment: @NathanWilson I could imagine arriving at that type by doing something like this: you start with a `[FilePath]` telling some resources to load from disk, and you have a loader of type `FilePath -> IO (Either Text Resource)` that might throw an error because of syntax errors. Each resource has some contained `Elements`, so you have an `Resource -> [Element]` accessor, and then some validator that does some computation on an `Element` but might discover invalid data, so it has type `Element -> Either Text Int`. You combine all these in the natural way, and arrive at a god-awful type.

Comment: Here's an alternative: change your loader to have type `loader :: FilePath -> ExceptT Text IO Resource`; your accessor can stay `elements :: Resource -> [Element]`; change your validator to have type `compute :: Element -> ExceptT Text IO Int`. Now the natural way of combining them lands you at `forM paths $ \path -> loader path >>= mapM compute . elements` which has the nice clean type `ExceptT Text IO [[Int]]`. The weaving of `Either Text`s and `IO` is hidden in the implementation of that monad's bind and happens at each step, so it never arrives at god-awful.

Comment: Wow that's much more elegant. And yes you've correctly deduced pretty much the exact sequence to arrive me at an `[IO (Either Text [Either Text Int])]` :).  I haven't really gotten the hang of monad transformers yet, but maybe this means it's time for me to dive in.